# How to show a list of users using listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform, listadapter

I am working on a social network app and I need to have an activity that displays all the data inside my user table in parse.com. I have tried this code but the result is always an empty blank white screen.
This is the code for the activity

```
public class UsersList extends Activity {
private ParseQueryAdapter<Userr> mainAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);
    ListView listhope = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlistlist);
    mainAdapter = new MyParseUserListAdaptor(this, Userr.class);
    listhope.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    mainAdapter.loadObjects();
 }
  [...]
}
```

and this is the layout file for the listview

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/usslist">
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/userlistlist"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the custom adapter I have created

```
public class MyParseUserListAdaptor extends ParseQueryAdapter<Userr> {

public MyParseUserListAdaptor(Context context,
                           Class<?extends ParseUser> clazz) {
    super(context, clazz);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getItemView(Userr userme, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.usertem, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(userme, v, parent);

    ParseImageView userlistpic = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView userListName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    TextView userListEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);

    userlistpic.setParseFile(userme.getPhotoFile());
    userListName.setText(userme.getUser_Name(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
    userListEmail.setText(userme.getUser_Email(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
    userlistpic.loadInBackground();

    return v;
}
}
```

and this is my Userr class

```
@ParseClassName("Userr")
public class Userr extends ParseUser {

public Userr() {
    // A default constructor is required.
}
```

and finally this is the listview item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/userittem">

<com.parse.ParseImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Mohamed Sherif"
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="mohamedsherifhazem@gmail.com"
    android:id="@+id/userEmail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
public String getUser_Name(ParseUser user) {
    String name =  user.get("name").toString();
    if (name != null)
        return name;
    else return "Anonymous";
}

public String getUser_Email(ParseUser user) {
    String email =  user.getEmail();
    if (email != null)
        return email;
    else return "Anonymous";
}

public ParseFile getPhotoFile() {
    return getParseFile("profile_picture");
}
}
```

Comment: What does the `loadObjects` method do? If it loads the adapter with the data to be diplayed in the `ListView`, does it call `notifyDatasetChanged()` at the end?

Comment: According to the documentation `loadObjects` should be called only when `autoLoad` is set to `false`. Reference: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Ur code structure is not so good. likewise u have a class calles User
expends Parseobject and u still have the method getUserEmail from an user object what.

I am now working in javascript.
But i believe in parse it was like ParseUser.get("ParseKey");

Comment: *Parse = android last line sorry

Comment: No  actually user class extends ParseUser